# Using different fonts/attributes in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt5, qtextedit

I have a problem with displaying a text to area with different attributes.

My project has a multi-threading build. I reach to GUI text area by using signal-slot mechanism. I put my texts to the text area like this;

```
addrMW->ui->printerArea->appendPlainText(command.Data);
```

I want to append my text to this area with different font, size, etc..

I'm using Qt Creator 2.7.2 / Qt 5.1. Could someone explain this to me with an example?

Comment: yeah, Qt Creator 2.7.2, based on Qt 5.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [QTextEdit with different text colors (Qt / C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857864/qtextedit-with-different-text-colors-qt-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a `rich` text edit. Luckily `QTextEdit` is able to handle that. Check the [acceptRichText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtextedit.html#acceptRichText-prop) property (which should be `true` by default).

Then the methods you're looking for are:

- [setCurrentCharFormat](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtextedit.html#setCurrentCharFormat)
- [setCurrentFont](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtextedit.html#setCurrentFont)
- [setFontFamily](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtextedit.html#setFontFamily)
- [setFontPointSize](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtextedit.html#setFontPointSize)
- etc...

Then, instead of `appendPlainText()` you should use `append()` to add text to the `QTextEdit`. Also see this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857864/qtextedit-with-different-text-colors-qt-c). As proposed in the accepted answer, you can also use html formatted text instead.

Comment: Thank you for your advices and solutions, i found my answer in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857864/qtextedit-with-different-text-colors-qt-c)

Comment: @srdrgkcn89 I thought so, that's why I added a link to that question in my answer.